# Excel VBA Lookup values to populate matching columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to lookup values from Master Data worksheet check if "CONDITION 1" is true and to populate with "Value" each column with header "SITE # 1" in Project Visit worksheet having empty row using VBA.

Note that number of row and columns will remain variable, hence I'm want to use `.UsedRange` to cut down unnecessary loops.

Screenshots

[image: Master Data]

[image: Project Visit]

Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set rng1 = Range("b3")

On Error Resume Next

Dim P_Row As Long
Dim P_Clm As Long

Table1 = Sheet2.Range("A:A") ' LOOKUP VALUE
Table2 = Sheet1.Range("A:B") ' Range of LOOKUP VECTOR
Dept_Row = Sheet2.Range(rng1.Address).Row ' CURRENT DUE FOR THE MONTH
Dept_Clm = Sheet2.Range(rng1.Address).Column

For Each cl In Table1
    Sheet2.Cells(P_Row, P_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
    Dept_Row = P_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: We're not going to write it for you. We might help you *fix* your code if you write some and create an example for us to verify your problem.

Comment: @nicomp code added

Comment: @AlexP I cannot get it to loop through each column and empty cells in used range